# Unity only sees child objects placed in even positions of the hierarchy window when accessing from script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I've got 2 children for an object, that when I try to access through any transform-child-get method, I will get an unexpected response.

So here's an object order that works in the hierarchy window:

Objects of interest in even positions

[image]

And here's an order that does not work:

Objects of interest in odd positions

[image]

The inactive objects are empty objects containing a transform component only. The active child are objects containing a transform and a spriterenderer component to create a 2D backdrop.
The parent contains multiple components to create a 3D animation.

Parent components

[image]

For some reason trying to access the children of this object dynamically, through any transform-child-get command I can find only looks through the child in the even positions in the hierarchy window.

For example, in image 1:

```
//Will see and return both active children
.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
.transform.GetChild(i);
.transform.childCount;
```

In image 2:

```
//Will see and return nothing
.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
.transform.GetChild(i);
//Will see and return both inactive children
.transform.childCount;
```

I cannot for the life of me work it out.
Unity Editor 2021.3.9f1, also tried in 10f1.
I have not tried remaking the project from scratch as it's quite large already and was hoping to find a solution first.

Any other ways to access children from a gameobject dynamically I can use to access their components?

EDIT:

```
List<int> pos = new List<int>();
int runningCount = 0;

if (win.lineNumber != -1) 
{
    pos = slot.lines[win.lineNumber].positions;
}

for (int reel = 0; reel < slot.reels.Count; reel++) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < slot.reels[0].symbols.Count - (slot.reelIndent * 2); i++) 
    {
        var color = new Color32();

        if (win.setIndex != 10) 
        {
            if (win.matches > runningCount && pos[reel] == slot.reelIndent + i) 
            {
                runningCount++;
                color = new Color32(255, 255, 255, 255);
            }
            else
            {
                color = new Color32(77, 69, 69, 255);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (win.matches > runningCount && slot.reels[reel].symbols[slot.reelIndent + i].GetComponent<SlotSymbol>().symbolIndex == 10) 
            {
                runningCount++;
                color = new Color32(255, 255, 255, 255);
            }
            else
            {
                color = new Color32(77, 69, 69, 255);
            }
        }

        if (slot.reels[reel].symbols[slot.reelIndent + i].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>())
            slot.reels[reel].symbols[slot.reelIndent + i].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = (color);
        if (slot.reels[reel].symbols[slot.reelIndent + i].GetComponent<Renderer>())
            slot.reels[reel].symbols[slot.reelIndent + i].GetComponent<Renderer>().material.SetColor("_EmissionColor", color);
        if (slot.reels[reel].symbols[slot.reelIndent + i].GetComponent<SlotSymbol>().symbolIndex == 9) 
        {
            slot.log("namee: "+ slot.reels[reel].symbols[slot.reelIndent + i].transform.childCount);

            Transform[] transforms = slot.reels[reel].symbols[slot.reelIndent + i].GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
            // slot.log("nameeee: "+slot.reels[reel].symbols[slot.reelIndent + i].transform.GetChild(0).name);
            foreach(Transform t in transforms)
            {
                slot.log("nameee: "+t);

                if (t.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>())
                        t.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = (color);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For further clarification, if I had a hierarchy window open showing all child objects of the parent in question named 1,2,3,4,etc..., when I try to access the children through any of the above methods, all odd numbered children will be treated as if they do not exist.
As far as I can tell, all those commands can only see the even numbered children.
AND, if I were to move or delete the first child from the hiearchy window, "1", it would now be flipped, I can only access all odd children.
*It does not matter if the objects are marked as active or inactive when it comes to trying to access them. Changing object "1" to inactive while in the first position will not effect anything when trying to access them from the script, it will only stop them from being active in the game window (As you would expect).

(Also it should be noted that as far as rendering these objects in the game window when playing, there are no issues. Everything displays properly and exists, only accessing them is an issue).

Comment: As for `GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>()` will return all active children **including the parent itself**! If you wanted inactive ones you need to pass `GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>(true)` .. that is by design and [API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentInChildren.html) note that it will of course also bubble further down the hierarchy

Comment: And I don't quite understand your tests ... `GetChild(i)` should return the child at given index no matter if it is enabled or not

Comment: If you only want to iterate all direct children you can use `foreach(Transform child in parentTransform){ ...}`

Comment: The inactive children are only there to make the code work, without them (with only the 2 active children) any of the above commands will only see and/or return the second object. If I were to switch their order in the hierarchy it would still only see/return the second child.

As for .GetChild(i), I may have been incorrect about it not seeing the inactive ones, that's my bad. But that's not necessary for what I'm doing.

Comment: foreach through the parentTransform will not work as intended.
It will only check the children in the even positions. So if I laid my hierarchy out like image 2 I would not see either active chidren, and if I delted both of the inactive children I'm not using, I would only loop through 1 of the objects (Whichever is in the second position).
*This isn't what I want to do, this is what's happening

Comment: please include your actual code .. it is hard to figure out what exactly you are trying to achieve

Comment: @derHugo I have updated the post with my code.
And I'd like to mention that I don't understand the problem either, it makes no sense that unity is acting this way.

Comment: `.transform.childCount` will return the total number of children /2, rounded down.

Comment: `As far as I can tell, all those commands can only see the even numbered children` that is definitely not the case ;) create a new empty scene add according hierarchy of empty GameObjects and a test script wit only iterating and printing them => works. It is definitely something in your code behaving unexpectedly ;)

Comment: Are you sure there are no two childs with the same name and the log message just gets collapsed in the console (this would mean the message is only displayed once but with a counter on the right how often that message was logged)

Comment: `Any other ways to access children from a gameobject dynamically I can use to access their components?` .. yes instead of doing what you do rather have a proper parent class like `Slot` or whatever name and reference all accordin children in according fields via the Inspector ... e.g. `public SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer; public Renderer renderer;` etc .. thn you can also get rid of all `GetComponent` calls .. or rather directly use `GetComponentsInChildren<SpriteRenderer>(true);` .. no need to loop over transforms